# Prometheus grafana alert query for all instances

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

I am new to grafana and prometheus,
I was just wondering, does anybody know if it is possibe to set up one alert w/ one query  that querys a multiude of different instances and will send alerts when one of the instances hit the treshold set.

I have numerous alerts set up for each instance and i want to minimise alerts any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you describe better what you're trying to alert, is it a CPU threshold for a given app instance, or something else?

Comment: Instances as in Prometheus instances or app instances?

Comment: Hello I mean instances as in servers, the alert would be for cpu/memory/disk space and network utilisation.

Comment: so you do have one central prometheus instance that node-exporters, presumably, write to? There's a great distance between querying multiple **prometheus** servers and a time series with multiple different labels for the different instances.

Comment: Yes we have a box with prometheus on it and we have windows exporter scrapping the metrics from the servers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your alerting rules can use metrics of different instances.

Simplest example of this:

```yaml
 # Alert for any instance that is unreachable.
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} is down."
```

This alerting rule checks if metric `up` returns 0 for any set of labels. If so, alert with the same set of labels as your metric (and a couple additional) is created.

If metric `up` returns 0 for multiple sets of metrics - alert will be created with every of this sets.

As you could see example alert rule includes summary and description. They are generated depending on labels `instance` and `job` of your initial metric.

Demo example of applied rules can be seen at [prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/rules)

More on configuration of [alerting](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) and [recording](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/) rules read in official documentation.